# Python I/O not creating new line

Tags: python, io

I have the following code:

```
lines[usernum] = str(user) + "\n"         
f = open('users.txt','w')
userstr = str(lines)
f.write(userstr)
```

Effectively I am modifying the `lines` list at `usernum`, then writing it back to the original file `'users.txt'`. However, even adding the "\n", everything gets written to one line rather than an individual line for each line in `lines`. Why is this?

Comment: What **exactly** do you expect `str(lines)` to do, and **why**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because `str(lines)` will not do what you expect it to do:

```
>>> lst = ['This', 'is a\n', 'fancy\n', 'list']
>>> print(str(lst))
['This', 'is a\n', 'fancy\n', 'list']
```

As you can see, it will write a representation of the list, and not print out the individual lines. You can use [`str.join`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) to combine the list elements:

```
lines[usernum] = str(user)
with open('users.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write('\n'.join(lines))
```

Using `'\n'` as the join character will make sure that a newline is inserted between each list element, so you do not need to take care of adding it to every item manually.

Furthermore, when working with files, it is recommended to use the `with` statement when opening them, to make sure that they are closed correctly when you are done working with them.

Comment: This seems to add a new line at the end of the file everytime I run this. How do I prevent that?

Comment: The join will only add newlines *between* list elements, and `f.write` itself will not terminate lines with newlines. So it’s probably that your last list item has a line break at the end. You can use `str.strip()` to get rid of leading and trailing whitespace in a string. If you want to apply that to all list elements, you could do this: `f.write('\n'.join(map(lambda x: x.strip(), lines)))`

Answer (score 1):

You are writing the string *representation* of the list to the file.

String representations of Python containers use the *representation* of the contents, not directly write strings.

Use the `writelines()` function to write a sequence of strings:

```
f.writelines(lines)
```

or write each line separately:

```
for line in lines:
    f.write(line)
```

or join the lines into one long string:

```
f.write(''.join(lines))
```

The latter also allows you to add the newlines at the time of writing, by using `\n` as the joining string:

```
f.write('\n'.join(lines))
```

where `lines` contains strings *without* newlines.

Answer (score 1):

Use a for-loop and `'\n'` to write each item on a new line:

```
with open('users.txt','w') as f:
    for line in lines:
        f.write('{}\n'.format(line))
```

Calling `str()` on a python object like `list` or `dict` simply returns the `str` version of that object, to write it's content to a file you should loop over it.

**Demo:**

```
lines = [1, 'foo', 3, 'bar']
with open('users.txt','w') as f:
    for line in lines:
        f.write('{}\n'.format(line))
...         
>>> !cat users.txt
1
foo
3
bar
```

Comment: this works but seems to always add a blank new line to the end of the document if I run it more than once

Comment: @user1045280 Use `f.write('\n'.join(str(x) for x in lines))` if you don't want a '\n' on the last line.